# 'Fatal: cherry-pick failed' with Git

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I was working on a branch `X`. I made a commit and pushed it.

Then I wanted to `cherry-pick` it to branch `Y`. But due to some unmerged files present, I got the following message:

```
error: 'cherry-pick' is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree,
hint: and then use 'git add/rm <file>' as
hint: appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit,
hint: or use 'git commit -a'.
fatal: cherry-pick failed
```

Now, I just want to delete my branch `Y`, then re-create the branch `Y` and then want to manually edit the file where I was trying to cherry-pick.

Currently, I'm unable to delete the branch as it is my working branch.
I cannot `checkout` any other branch. I'm getting the following error on trying to change the branch.

```
mod/assign/locallib.php: needs merge
error: you need to resolve your current index first
```

I just need to delete the branch `Y`, without losing anything on branch `X`.

**EDIT #1**

I edited the file `mod/assign/locallib.php`

On doing `git status`, I get:

```
# On branch MDL-38267_24
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#   both modified:      mod/assign/locallib.php
#
```

What file should I add in `git add ..` ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since you have already edited the conflict file, you just need

```
git add mod/assign/locallib.php
```

then

```
git cherry-pick --continue
```

Answer (score 2):

You attempted to do a merge (via either `git merge` or `git pull`) and have files that have conflicts that are not resolved.  If you do `git status`, you will likely see file(s) listed as being 'changed by both'.  You need to take care of this before you do anything else.

Do `git mergetool` and it will bring up the files one at a time.  Fix the file so that the conflicts are resolved and then you should be able to proceed.

Comment: Please see my edits I made to the question. I mean the file which I modified and the file which is returned by `git status` are the same. How should I resolve the issue I'm having?

Comment: You need to resolve the conflict or `git reset` the file to an un-conflicted state.  Depending on what you did that caused the conflict.